# Cannot run '>' for a terminal command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, doc

thanks for helping me out.

I am trying to run antiword from python to convert .docx to .doc. I have used subprocess for the task.

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["antiword","/home/mypath/document.doc",">","/home/mypath/document.docx"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
```

But it return the error,

```
I can't open '>' for reading
I can't open '/home/mypath/document.docx' for reading
```

But the same command works in terminal

```
antiword /home/mypath/document.doc > /home/mypath/document.docx
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` character is interpreted by the shell as output stream redirection.  However, `subprocess` doesn't use a shell, so there is nothing to interpret the `>` character as redirection.  Hence the `>` character will be passed on to the command.  After all, it is a perfectly-legal filename: how is `subprocess` supposed to know you don't actually have a file named `>`?

It's not clear why you are attempting to redirect the output of `antiword` to a file and also read the output in the variable `output`.  If it's redirected to a file, there will be nothing to read in `output`.

If you want to redirect the output of a `subprocess` call to a file, open the file for writing in Python and pass the opened file to `subprocess.Popen`:

```py
with open("/home/mypath/document.docx", "wb") as outfile:
    test = subprocess.Popen(["antiword","/home/mypath/document.doc"], stdout=outfile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    error = test.communicate()[1]
```

It's possible that the process may write to its standard error stream, so I've captured anything that gets written to that in the variable `error`.

Comment: it works, just to know how can I know which index value of communicate contains what, any doc or something like that

Comment: @Anil: From the [`subprocess` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), "`communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`".